# Android app throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError for all devices after being published to the app store

Tags: java, android, kotlin, error-handling

We're running in to a very weird issue where our Android app is throwing an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` after being published to the play store. If the exact APK that was uploaded to to Google Play Console is installed manually on an Android phone, the app works just fine but if we either

1. Download the app from the goole play store after it gets approved
2. Download any device-specific APK from "App Bundle Explorer" from the Google Play Console

Then, the app throws the follow error on startup.

```
java.lang. UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in
...
```

This is super weird because the exact same APK, when installed directly on device after exporting from android studio works fine.

Would love some pointers as to why this might only be happening in the above cases.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError have you seen this ?

Comment: @AyodeleKayode Yes, but it's weird that this only happens when the app is downloaded from the play store or google play console. It doesn't happen in the emulator or when I build and directly install the APK on my phone.

Comment: yeah, you using android studio ?

Comment: @AyodeleKayode yes

Comment: Just want to add i am seeing this issue also. But it started to happen after switching to App Bundle in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The App was being signed twice. The app was signed when exported, and then again when uploaded too Google Play Store.